# Inserting date into Oracle table without To_Date

Tags: sql, oracle, rhino

I am using open adaptor technology and need to insert date into my sql table column which is in date format. I am passing my date extracted from a csv as a java date format to sql. I use javascript rhino (openadaptor script processor) to convert js date into java format.

```
var val1=oa_data.get('UPDATED ON DATE TIME'); //Extracts date from csv
var dateJava = new java.util.Date();
dateJava =  java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(val1));
```

I get the following exception on running this script:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Is there a way to insert the date without using the To_Date method in sql using javascript..

Comment: You need to change the default date format using `alter session set nls_date_format = ...` before you can send a string literal formatted that way.

Comment: You are right. We can insert the date directly by setting nls date format in sql. However I am getting the same exception while inserting via the prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. Somewhere there is probably a java preparedstatement that is doing an insert, and you are binding the variable to that statement before executing it.

That binding should be done as a date, not a string.

Comment: Thank you for the response, you are partially right. Prepared statements are being  created by the open adaptor. However all variables are being sent as string type by the database writer, that is the issue.